# $L^1$ Convergence of expectation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, filtrations

The underlying space is a probability space.

Suppose we have a filtration $\{\mathscr{F}_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and denote $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} \mathscr{F}_n$ by $\mathscr{F}_\infty$.

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ s.t. $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$.

In class there was a statement that $\mathbb E[X_n|\mathscr F_n]\to \mathbb E[X|\mathscr F_\infty]$ in $L^1$ without proof.

I think this should be a very standard result in the theory. Can anyone give me a reference for the proof? Thanks!

Comment: $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} \mathscr{F}_n$ is not a $\sigma-$ field.

Comment: Have you studied Martingale Convergence Theorem under uniform integrability?

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry for the late reply. I have studied Martingale Convergence Theorem and some theorems (about convergences) related to uniform integrability. But I am not sure what is Martingale Convergence Theorem under uniform integrability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean $\mathcal F_\infty=\sigma(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal F_n)$.

The result can be deduced from a combination of classic properties:

- $(\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a martingale (very easy, see for instance [Doob martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob_martingale))
- $(\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly integrable (easy consequence of the [de la Vallée-Poussin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems))
- From the above we deduce that $(\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $L^1$ to some $X_\infty$ ($(\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly integrable so bounded in $L^1$, so by [Doob's martingale convergence theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems) it converges almost surely and therefore in probability to an integrable random variable, and uniform integrability + convergence in probability is equivalent to convergence in $L^1$).
- Up to replacing $X_\infty$ with $\liminf_{n\to+\infty}X_n$ we can suppose that $X_\infty$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$-measurable.
- We can show that $X_\infty=\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_\infty]$ ($\{A\in\mathcal F_\infty\mid\mathbb E[X1_A]=\mathbb E[X_\infty1_A]\}$ is $\lambda$-system which contains $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal F_n$ and therefore $\mathcal F_\infty$ by the [$\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Sierpi%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Dynkin%27s_%CF%80-%CE%BB_theorem)).
- We deduce that $(\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $L^1$ to $\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_\infty]$.
- By $L^1$ continuity of the conditional expectation,
  $$
  \Vert\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_n]-\mathbb E[X_n\vert\mathcal F_n]\Vert_{L^1}\le\Vert X_n-X\Vert_{L^1},
  $$
  hence $(\mathbb E[X_n\vert\mathcal F_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $L^1$ to $\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal F_\infty]$.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. Thanks Will !